# How to build a Debian/Ubuntu package from source cross-architecture, without qemu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, cross-compiling, packaging

How do I cross-build an Ubuntu package for ARM on x86?

I know I can emulate an ARM system with `chroot` and `qemu-arm-static`, but does a more straightforward way exist, with only specifying toolchain and target architecture?

Comment: Do you need a *.deb file at the end or are you just interested in cross-compiling and then coping binary to your target device?